# why is session not being set sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a simple join room code for a multiplayer game.

The image below is the index page where the user first needs to type a name and then join the room.

[image]

Here two people join the room. One client is a chrome and another client is firefox. I did it so that two different sessions could be created.

[image]

After clicking join by both clients both click on join and they are taken to startgame page as shown below. The image below is a success scenerio since they both display their respective ids.

[image]

Most of the times, one id is missing. The error view is shown in the following image. I am wondering why is the id missing for one user or in other words why is the session not being set for one user. I have included below all the code of this simple application. I have been stuck on this issue for a while now so i am finally turning to stackoverflow for some directions. I appreciate your help a lot! Thanks!
Often times the case is as follows. One id is missing for one client or user.

[image]
The code is as follows:

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def userCount

        render plain: User.count

    end


    def join

        n = params[:name]

        u = User.create(name: n)

        session[:current_user_id] = u.id


        render plain: User.count

    end    


    def startGame


        @my_id = session[:current_user_id]


    end


end
```

The view files are as follows:

Index page(First page)

**index.html.erb**

```
<label> Status: </label>
<span id="status"> </span>



<br>
<br>


<input type="text" id="name"> </input>
<button id="join"> Join </button>
<br>
<button id="enterroom"> Enter Room </button>



<script>




var refreshId = setInterval(function() {


    $.get( "/userCount", function( data ) {


          $('#status').text(data);





    });



}, 1000);





$( "#join" ).click(function() {


    $.post( "/join", { name: $('#name').val() })
      .done(function( data ) {



      });




});





$( "#enterroom" ).click(function() {



        window.location.replace("/startGame");


});





</script>
```

The page after join is complete

**startGame.html.erb**

```
<h1> Ok game has started... </h1>

<br>

<h1> My id is <%= @my_id %> </h1>
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161211055722) do


  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root 'hello#index'

    get '/userCount' => 'hello#userCount'
    post '/join' => 'hello#join'
    get '/startGame' => 'hello#startGame'

end
```

**UPDATE:**

ok if i comment the following code in index.html.erb then the ids are generated everytime for both users. So, looks like the culprit is this section of code but i am confused why this is the case. The following code in index file is responsible for updating the total user count every 1 second. Could it be that when join is clicked a post request is prepared but this get call will intercept that call or void that call? Thanks!

```
/*
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {


    $.get( "/userCount", function( data ) {


          $('#status').text(data);





    });



}, 1000);

*/
```

**UPDATE2:**

Ok i have verified that the session is being set in the join method but before the startGame method is executed, the session or session[:current_user_id] is being reset. I am wondering why is the session being reset at some point after the session is successfully set. Thanks!

**UPDATE3:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: I think it is a local problem. I just copied all your code and unless you have some sort of User validation, it works 100% for me. The problem must be with c9 cloud platform. Did you open the same project in different browsers ?

Comment: @AlexanderLuna it fails if you try few times. please note that for second run you have to rake db:reset so that the database doesnt have any user records.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna i think the problem is boiling down to why is the session after being set in join method being reset when it reaches startGame.

Comment: Nope, I reset and quit the server 4 times and everytime it worked.

Comment: Do you have any User validations ? I opened the local database and the users are even saved. I'm pretty sure it is a problem with c9 not the code.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna the problem exists even on heroku platform. i have deployed the app to heroku from c9 and the same bug can be reproduced. User has no validations. I will add the model definitions above.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the following line is the culprit:

`u = User.create(name: n)`

You aren't testing whether that user is valid or errors were generated and simply assigning it to the session:

```
session[:current_user_id] = u.id
```

If there were errors then `u.id` would be nil and would explain why you don't see the id in the view.

You haven't actually shown the User model in your question but I suspect that you have a unique validation for name and this is the reason that the user isn't being created. Quite easy to find out if this is the case, simply put some debug in:

```
u = User.create(name: n)
puts u.valid?
puts u.errors.messages
session[:current_user_id] = u.id
```

To resolve this you should either remove the constraint/validation, or you should be testing for the error and handling it appropriately within your controller.

Comment: Thanks David. Please look at the above updated post. I have added an UPDATE: section.

Comment: I verified that when this error occurs the ids are generated for both users or in other words both user models are saved to database.

Answer (score 0):

I made a clone of your app and it runs perfectly fine. The records are saved correctly even without a name.

I believe the problem is the c9 cloud platform from where you are testing your code. On my Local machine running localhost it works.

Comment: thanks Alexander but i verified that the users were created when this error occurs. also at this point i am not concerned about best practices. i just want to track the bug. i have updated my post above. the problem seems to be the commented code. if i comment it out then it works every time and if i un-comment it then it fails most of the time. please let me know if you know  the reason. thanks!